# How to freeDraw fabric.Path with certain offset to it?

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I need to be able to draw a fabric.Path using fabric's freeDrawingBrush with certain offset from where mouse hits canvas.

For instance: 
      if canvas.getPointer() returns point p = {x: 100, y: 100},
      I want fabric to draw that point on newP = {x: p.x + 20, y: p.y + 20} (or whatever) ;

I'm not able to get this to work. I have tried for several days with absolutely no luck.

```
@Component({

  private Brush: any;
  private canvas:

  constructor() {
     this.Brush = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.PencilBrush, {
     type: 'myBrush',
     color: 'rgb(134, 10, 230)',
         width: 16,

     initialize: function(canvas) {
         this.callSuper('initialize', canvas);
      },                
    onMouseDown: function(pointer) {
          this.callSuper('onMouseDown', pointer);
  },
    onMouseMove: function(pointer) {
         this.callSuper('onMouseMove', pointer);
      },
  _render: function(ctx) {
     this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
     }
   });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

    if (this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush) {
      this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush = this.Brush;
    }
    canvas.on("mouse:down", (e) => { 
    let pointer = canvas.getPointer(),
        point = { x: pointer.x + 20, y: pointer.y + 20 };

    Brush.onMouseDown(point);
   }
 }
}
```

It only work for the first drawned path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution myself. 
First, I freeDraw a path as one would normally do using `canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'transparent';`

Then in the canvas event:

```
canvas.on('path:created', (o) => { 
        let paths = canvas.getObjects('path').length;
        this.drawPath(o.path);
});
```

I remove that path only to redraw it with options I desire like this:

```
drawPath(path) {
    canvas.remove(path);

    let offsetY, offsetX, uiValue = this.uiValue;

    //you can use any value you want
    if(this.uiValue < 0){
        offsetY = path.top + 50;
        offsetX = path.left - 50;
    }
    else if(this.uiValue > 0){
        offsetY = path.top + 50;
        offsetX = path.left + 50;
    }

    path.setOptions({
        top: offsetY,
        left: offsetX,
        selectable: false,
        fill: 'transparent', //this did the trick, otherwise it will 
                             //'clipTo' instead of just drawing the path
        stroke: 'blue',
        color: 'blue',      
        globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-out'
    });

    canvas.add(path).renderAll();       
}
```

That's it, new path will appear exactly where you want.